# Properties of black body to emit radio waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

Usually the wavelengths of the radiation of a black body is like in the sketch below (from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzer_K%C3%B6rper)):

[image]

Which properties are needed to make a black body to radiate in the range of radio waves?

Comment: A blackbody radiates at all wavelengths. The Planck function is $>0$ for all $\lambda$. For radio waves to be anywhere near the peak of the Planck function, then clearly the blackbody has to be very cold. Are you asking any more than this? A surface area and a temperature are the only relevant properties that a blackbody has.

Comment: @Rob For a [medium frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_frequency) how cold should the body be and how to get a measurable radiation or better how to get a radiation ot 1Watt?

Answer (score 1):

The blackbody radiates electromagnetic waves at all wavelengths $\lambda$, thus also in the radio wave range (ca 1m to kilometers). However, there is a strong dependence of intensity on wavelength and an increase with temperature, as shown in your graph. For a given absolute temperature T, the total emitted spectral power density per square meter $I(\lambda, T)$ over all angles diminishes at long wavelengths, following in the radio wave region approximately the *Raleigh-Jeans* law $$I(\lambda, T)=\frac{2\pi c kT}{\lambda^4} Wm^{-3}$$ where c is the light speed and k is the Boltzmann constant. The radio wave emission at $\lambda$ is thus proportional to the temperature T.